# Rails 4 Client Side Validation with Simple Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, client-side-validation

I have created an app, where I require a form to be submitted remotely. If the form does not pass validation, errors need to be displayed. If it is submitted successfully, the for should be cleared. I am using the [Reform](https://github.com/apotonick/reform) gem to strip validation logic out of my models.

I have installed the [client_side_validations](https://github.com/DavyJonesLocker/client_side_validations) as well as [client_side_validations-simple_form](https://github.com/DavyJonesLocker/client_side_validations-simple_form) gems as per the installation instructions. For some reason though, validation errors are not displaying and I'm not sure why... I've tried all the debugging options I could think of.

Here is my code:

1. foo_form.rb

   ```
   class FooForm < ApplicationForm

     property :bar, validates: {
     presence:     true
     },client_validations: { class: 'Foo' }

   end
   ```
2. foos_controller.rb

   ```
   def create 
     @foo = FooForm.new( Foo.new )
     respond_to do |format|
       if @foo.validate(params[ :foo ])
         @foo.save
         format.html { redirect_to root_path }
         format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @foo.model }
       else
         format.html { render :new }
         format.json { render json: @foo.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
       end
     end
   end
   ```
3. form.haml

   ```
   = simple_form_for @foo, url: foos_path, as: :foo, remote: true, validate: true do |f|
   .input-field
     = f.input :bar

   .right-align.card-button
     = f.button :submit, class: "waves-light blue", data: { disable_with: "Loading..." }
   ```

Could anybody help with identifying what I'm missing? Thanks

Comment: Did you mean to `format.html { render :new }` on validation failure for html but show an error for json?

Comment: @Pyrce I think that's the way the scaffold was generated if I remember correctly. If not then no I didn't :-)

Comment: ahh yes the default template does do that -- had to remind myself that the form relies on the simple_form_for to render the errors correctly rather than passing a failing status code